# Bottom navigation bar malfunctions when navigating from a fragment

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I'm using the bottom navigation bar with the navigation component

To make the two components work together I called:

```
bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Everything works as expected except when I navigate from inside a fragment instead of the bottom navigation bar

[image]

"View all" opens the same fragment as "Reports" from the bottom navigation bar

```
binding.viewAllScansTv.setOnClickListener {
    val action = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToReportsFragment()
    navController.navigate(action)
}
```

After clicking on "View all", the fragment is opened, the "Reports" button gets selected, however, **navigating back "Home" does not work anymore**

**How can I fix this weird behavior?**

The nav graph:

```
<navigation app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.package.name.ui.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="MainFragment"> 
        <action                android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_reportsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/reportsFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

The bottom navigation menu:

```
<menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:title="Home"/>    
    <item
        android:id="@+id/reportsFragment"
        android:title="Reports"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:title="My account"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Please share your navGraphs; need to see the `actionMainFragmentToReportsFragment`

Comment: I updated the question and added the nav graph and the bottom navigation menu

Comment: Not sure if you're using the right navController; can you use `findNavController().navigate(action)` instead

Comment: tried it. nothing changes

Comment: Looks like an duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71565073/1676363).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [@ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake) mentioned in a comment, a similar question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71565073/why-does-navigation-not-work-in-the-navigation-drawer-activity-template-with-ver)

What I ended up doing was replacing

```
val action = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToReportsFragment()
navController.navigate(action)
```

with

```
val item = mainBottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.reportsFragment)
NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
```

So basically I used the `NavigationUI` API to navigate so that it correctly tracks the back stack. The same `NavigationUI` API is being used by the `BottomNavigationView` internally

Answer (score 3):

Your current answer is fine but if you need to pass arguments it wont work, So use this

In the Navigation XML add these lines to the action

```
app:launchSingleTop="true"
app:popUpTo="@+id/main_navigation"
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

And make sure `app:popUpTo="@+id/main_navigation"` has the same id as your navigation xml

So the final action should look like:

```
     <action
            android:id="@+id/action_cameraFragment_to_searchFragment"
            app:destination="@id/searchFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/main_navigation"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
```

And Navigate normally using the action

```
val action = CameraFragmentDirections.actionCameraFragmentToSearchFragment()
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a click listener on any view should have the same effect as if the user taps the corresponding item in the bottom navigation. So you need to call setSelectedItemId() on the BottomNavigationView.

val mainBottomNav =
activity?.findViewById(R.id.homeBottomNavigation)
mainBottomNav?.selectedItemId = R.id.baseHomeFragment